# Ubuntu 16.04 slow after login but recovers

Tags: 16.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC. The first problem is that my system takes time to boot. Secondly, after login, it becomes real slow. I click on my chrome icon and it does not launch. I need to click on the icon atleast 3-4 times to open. I try to open the terminal  (Ctrl + Alt + T) and it takes time. Also, if I repeatedly try to launch them, the system hangs and doesn't allow me to click anywhere. However, after about 15-20 minutes, it works as normal!

This problem started after I forced shutdown(using power button) once. It started giving disk errors on boot. I managed to fix them somehow. I will post those errors if I find them (and the threads with solutions too). Here is some data that might help

Following is the output of `lsblk -l -a`

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda     8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
sda1    8:1    0   286M  0 part /boot/efi
sda2    8:2    0 279.4G  0 part /home
sda3    8:3    0 355.1G  0 part /
sda4    8:4    0 296.8G  0 part /media/divush/data
sr0    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0   7:0    0         0 loop 
loop1   7:1    0         0 loop 
loop2   7:2    0         0 loop 
loop3   7:3    0         0 loop 
loop4   7:4    0         0 loop 
loop5   7:5    0         0 loop 
loop6   7:6    0         0 loop 
loop7   7:7    0         0 loop
```

Output from `fdisk -l` :

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DC68EEDD-5156-4BD6-81E4-6E30FC15DEF0

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     587775    585728   286M EFI System
/dev/sda2      587776  586524671 585936896 279.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   586524672 1331202047 744677376 355.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  1331202048 1953523119 622321072 296.8G Linux filesystem
```

Is this a filesystem issue?

Comment: How long does it take to boot? Have you run a fsck? If you log into the Guest account, does it work any better?

Comment: Does running `sudo iotop` in a terminal show anything using a lot of IO when the system is slow?